# PHP API YouTube Video Tags Not Retrieving

Tags: video, tags, youtube-api, feed

I am having difficultly retrieving video tags from a PHP YouTube video feed.

All video properties other than the video tags can be retrieved successfully.

Please help me and Happy New Years!

Part of my code is below:

```
foreach ($videoFeed as $videoEntry ) {
if ( $count < 50) {
$vidtitle[$count] = $videoEntry->getVideoTitle();  
$vidid[$count] = $videoEntry->getVideoId(); 
$vidcategory[$count] = $videoEntry->getVideoCategory();
$vidtags[$count] = implode(", ", $videoEntry->getVideoTags());
$vidwatchpage[$count] = $videoEntry->getVideoWatchPageUrl();
$vidduration[$count] = $videoEntry->getVideoDuration();
$vidviewcount[$count] = $videoEntry->getVideoViewCount();
```